# Starting my app from home button

Tags: android

Is there any way  to launch my Android application   when I  press  home button with a long press action

I tried to configure my main activity like this

```
<activity android:name="AwesomeActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action.  android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.android.systemui.action_assist_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/app_icon"/>
</activity>  but doesn't work for me
```

Comment: I've never tried, but I would be very surprised if that would be possible. Imagine any developer could just override the home button functionality to launch his app. That would be quite intrusive. And how should that work if multiple apps try to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way. You can't override HOME button in an unrooted device.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#keycode_home

> KEYCODE_HOME
>   added in API level 1
>   int KEYCODE_HOME
>   Key code constant: Home key. This key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications.